# Cocoa Mac OSX application turn off sound

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, libvlc

i have faced, witch simple quoestion, i didin't find in google, or in any forum. How to turn application audio/sound off? like mute? i wan't to make checkbox witch controlls sound of application.

I would be grateful for detailed definition

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the [source code](http://serial-remote-mac.googlecode.com/svn-history/r11/trunk/SoundController.m):

```
- (void)setDefaultAudioDevice
{
    UInt32 propertySize = 0;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;

    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;
    propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);

    status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &outputDeviceID); 

    if(status) 
    {
        // Error
        return;
    }
}

- (void)muteHardwareVolume
{
    UInt32 propertySize = 0;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;

    [self setDefaultAudioDevice];

    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;

    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyMute;

    propertySize = sizeof(UInt32);
    UInt32 mute = 1;
    status = AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL,    propertySize, &mute);

    if(status) 
    {
        // Error
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hy, thanks for replay, it's failed "propertyAOPA" undentified, you added so much code, but basicly if there any command like [NSApp setmute:True] or [VLCAudio setvolume:0]; im usling libvlc, on OSX 10.9. I know there is simple command thats turining off

Comment: Hi! I didn't see something like [NSApp setmute:True] or [VLCAudio setvolume:0], only for QTMovie or AVPlayer but not for the system. For proper compiling example you need include framework #import < AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h > And declare outputDeviceID

Comment: Could you explain how to declare outputDeviceID? ,

Comment: You can take a look at source code URL which I provided to you in Answer. But for declaring outputDeviceID you need something like this
AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = kAudioObjectUnknown; as a static variable or instance variable of interface.

Comment: "_AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData", referenced from:
      -[Controller setDefaultAudioDevice] in Controller.o
  "_AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData", referenced from:
      -[Controller muteHardwareVolume] in Controller.o             witch place i have to add AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = kAudioObjectUnknown;

Comment: You need add framework AudioToolbox to the project:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqSVlwBOvic

Comment: OK, atm there is no bug to build, but only sound on working, i modified little code and did this - (IBAction)setDefaultAudioDevice:(id)sender, for setdefaultaudiodevice works fine, i think, can't test it, but in output there is no error, but mutehardvarevolume, i get errors, -[Controller setDefaultAudioDevice]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ok, atm, i muting system sound, but not application :) i got 2 windows witch have sound, is there possible way to mute curret window>? or all application?

Comment: Oh Im sorry I didnt see that you need APPLICATION instead of System. Which one sounds do you want to turn off? Who plays this sounds?

Comment: Yes, i want to disable only application sounds, its libvlc streams, how to disable application sound? [NSApp setvolume:false];? is there command like this?